# Disappearing books in edit cv section?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

When I click my profile and go to my developer story even my traditional cv I see the following Books:

[image]

But If I go to my profile and click Edit CV and go to the books section I see this:

[image]

What happened to my books, as an FYI I had deleted CLR Via C# quite a while ago...and then added two design books I've read recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. The Careers CV and the Developer Story coexist independently while we're on private beta. Therefore, except for your job search preferences, any edits you make on your CV will not be reflected on the Developer Story and vice-versa.

This is a temporary inconvenience until we're out of the alpha/beta phase. We'll be gradually merging the Careers CV into the Developer Story.